# How to detect locked screen in Tasker?

Tags: tasker

I'd like to be able to detect a locked screen in Tasker without polling.

https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/3y3kpx/how_to_query_tasker_if_the_screen_is_locked_or_not/ has a solution that polls.

Answer (score 6):

Create a profile `Screen Locked` triggered on the event `Display Off` and calling a task that sets a variable `%SCREEN_LOCKED` to `true` iff `%SCREEN` is `off`.

Create another profile `Screen Unlocked` triggered on the event `Display Unlocked` and calling a task that sets `%SCREEN_LOCKED` to `false`.

If you'd like for a profile to be triggered (or not) if the screen is locked:
Create a third profile `Display Locked` triggered on `%SCREEN_LOCKED` being `true` and calling some NoOp task (which does pretty much nothing) then use the `Profile Active` trigger on the profile conditional on screen lock state.

Comment: Why do you need to check `iff %SCREEN is off`?

Comment: I forgot why that condition is there. Try it without it.